# How to use else-if condition in a view in SQL server?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I know that an *if* condition can be achieved using the `CASE` statement:

```
CASE
    WHEN <condition>
        x
    ELSE
        z
END
```

but how to do that for an *else-if* condition?

Something like this (pseudo code):

```
CASE
    WHEN <condition>
        x
    ELSE-IF <condition>
        y
    ELSE
        z
END
```

My code as of now:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[v_myview1]
AS
    SELECT 
        ci.aDate, ci.Currency, ci.lim, ci.LimitUS,
        pa.Date as AmtDate,
        pa.Payment as AmtPayment,
        CASE 
            WHEN (ci.aDate - pa.Date) < 0 THEN ci.LimitUS
            --ELSE IF
            --WHEN (ci.lim - pa.Payment) < 0 THEN 'a'
            ELSE 'b'
        END AS Estimate,
    FROM
        dbo.Amt pa
    JOIN 
        dbo.CrInfo ci ON ci.pr_key = pa.pr_key
    JOIN
        dbo.rates tr ON rt.Currency = ci.Currency 
    WHERE 
        ci.mk = 2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the second case like this:

```
CASE 
WHEN (ci.aDate - pa.Date) < 0 THEN  ci.LimitUS
WHEN (ci.lim - pa.Payment) < 0 THEN 'a'
ELSE 'b'
```

Comment: As Rahul has pointed out, case statements do not cascade in T-SQL and the statement will terminate on the first clause which matches. i.e. all `WHEN` statements are equivalent to `ELSE IF`